# Font awesome not working in loop/from variable?

Tags: php, html, laravel, font-awesome, laravel-5.7

I'm using Laravel 5.7 and just got font awesome to work when putting icons staticly into my page, but when they're fetched there from an object they don't seem to work.

#### This is my index page:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
    {{$data['hosts'][0]->icon}}
    <br>
    <i class="far fa-question-circle"></i>
@endsection
```

#### It displays like this:

[image]

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: use `{!! $data['hosts'][0]->icon !!}` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your code is being escaped. As per Laravel's [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#displaying-data), try using {!! !!} like:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
    {!! $data['hosts'][0]->icon !!}
    <br>
    <i class="far fa-question-circle"></i>
@endsection
```

Answer (score 1):

You are outputting HTML from the icon property, use this instead :

```
{!! data['hosts'][0]->icon !!}
```

{{ .. }} will treat everything inside it as string.